# Fastest way to take screenshot in headless browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, screen-scraping

I'm writing a script to take thousands of screenshots using a headless browser. Here's my simplified code:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(
#    ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
url = 'https://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html'
driver.get(url)
driver.set_window_size(1600, 2000)
driver.save_screenshot(save_path)
```

Currently, the following line takes ~1.5 seconds to run: `driver.save_screenshot(save_path)`. I'm trying to decrease this time to as close to the theoretical minimum as possible. The save likely takes a long time since I resize the window to capture the entire page.

So, I'm trying to determine my bottleneck. Is this I/O bound? Or bound by the speed of the Chrome driver? Are there faster libraries for taking screenshots?

Comment: are you closing and opening a new chrome / driver for each url? or are you opening and resizing once, then just calling in a loop `get` and `save_screenshot`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I'm re-using the instance and resizing once. The 1.5 seconds mentioned was the wall time of the `save_screenshot` method, only. I updated the driver to PhantomJS, which decreased the time to 0.3 seconds. Trying to get that down further, though.